# How to upload image after capturing it via webcam in PHP

Tags: php, flash

I am writing a php application where user will capture photo via webcam I am successful in capturing and saving the image on server. I am using flash for capturing the photo. 
 But I want to save this photo name (eg. enquiry_1391451289.jpg) in database when user submit the form this photocapture part is accessed from a php form. So basically I need this photo name to reture back on form
.Database name is "es_admission" and field name is "photo".
When I click on SAVE button (flash) it invoke the below mentioned code which saves the photo on server under images/enquiry_images folder -

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['eschools']['admin_user']) || $_SESSION['eschools']['admin_user']=="" ) {
    header('location: ./?pid=1&unauth=0');
    exit;
    }

//Now get the encoded image form flash through HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
if(isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){
    $jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    $img = $_GET["img"];
        $image_name="enquiry_".mktime(). ".jpg";
    //image Directory
    $filename = "images/enquiry_images/".$image_name;
    $_SESSION['capture_name']=$image_name;
    file_put_contents($filename, $jpg);
} else{
    //show error if image is not recived 
    echo "Encoded JPEG information not received.";
}
?>
```

For reference you can see demo here http://cbsecsnip.in/photocapture/ If you see successfully message that means the image is saved but after this how to upload I am not getting any way.

Need advices/suggestions.
Thank you

Comment: I really don't see where your problem is. The hardest part is done already. Once the file is on the server, just enter the path where you copied it to into the database... you got the image's name in `$image_name` already, so just put that value inside your database and you'Re done?

Comment: @JohannesH. Sorry for insufficient information. Actully this photo capturing code is accessed from a php form which is filled by user from there they click on a button take photo and this application starts now after saving this taking and photo they close the window and come back on form and fill rest of the form now they submit the form. Here the problem how I will get that image name Now?

Comment: YOu stored it in the session, right? so it's there, ready to be read again. Only thing you have to make sure is that the browser includes the session ID in the request - the same one flashed used when uploading the image.

Comment: @JohannesH. Thanx a lot for showing me the way. If you don't mind I am asking 1 more question related to same topic. I am trying to get the Enquiry number from form.php to this save.php because I want the name of image as enquiry_no+enquiry.jpg (eg. 2571_enquiry.jpg)

Comment: if you already got session management in place, i'd just use them :)

Comment: @JohannesH. I passed the reg_no using javascript when take photo button is clicked here is the code - `<script type="text/javascript">
function popup_letter(url) {
var regino = document.getElementById('reg_no').value;
var width  = 700;
var height = 450;

var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;
params += ', directories=no';
params += ', location=no';
newwin=window.open(url+regino,'windowname5', params);
if (window.focus){ newwin.focus() } return false;
}
</script> ` Session can't used in Javascript

Comment: what'S reg_no, and how is that related to the enquiry_no? to be honest, I'm completely lost right now... you migth want to go into details about your data flow some more.

Comment: @JohannesH. I have 3 files->1)form.php this file contain textbox for Registration Number textbox id=reg_no, above JS for opening the swf file in separate window file name is capture.php where .swf file is used and the image on which user will click for getting this window `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup_letter('?pid=141&amp;reg_no=')" ><img src="images/capture35.png" name="capture" title="Capture Image" border="0" alt="Capture Photo" /></a>`. Now from form onclick capture.php opens there is swf file from that save.php opens and save the image. form.php->capture.php->save.php

Comment: may be this one can help you http://codingbin.com/capture-webcam-image-with-php-and-jquery/